# React tutorial. Files in root directory not updating after server is run

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, facebook, reactjs

I'm following the React tutorial here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html which is fine. I have the files downloaded and i have run the server which I can see at http://localhost:3000

The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to update any of the files in the directory. The changes are not being applied.

I'm being told to delete the `examples.js` line before I start so I no longer see the completed tutorial and start from scratch. Even when I do, nothing happens. I deleted a bunch of code from the `package.json` as well just for testing but no changes.

I feel I'm missing something after running the server and making changes to files to allow this to happen. Does anyone have any ideas? Reloading the server doesnt have an effect either.

Below is the code for the tutorial index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      // To get started with this tutorial running your own code, simply remove
      // the script tag loading scripts/example.js and start writing code here.
    </script>
  </body>
```

thanks

Comment: you probably need to restart the server, maybe it's not auto reloading?

Comment: yeah i tried that as well. still nothing happend @Luuk

Comment: hmmm, okay, I'm at work at the moment and don't have node installed on this PC, if this question isn't answered by the time I get home, I'll see if I can work it out for you.

Comment: infact, dont worry about it. turns out i was editing the files in my 'Downloads' folder instead of 'Sites'. Idiot haha. thanks anyway @Luuk

Comment: Well, at least you found the "solution" on your own :D

Comment: nice, have fun learning react